# Grabbing Sequence Numbers of a tcp-packet

Tags: c++, linux, tcp

Is there any way to use the tcpdump command in such a way to capture only the sequence numbers(or in fact grab it) of the packets and store it in a variable?
I need to do this from inside a C++ program. Any help appreciated.

(I am using **nemesis-tcp** to send the packets from one system and **tcpdump** command to capture these packets at the receiver)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the pcap library](http://www.tcpdump.org/) and [the official walk-through](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) is a very good introduction. Especially look at the `seq` in tcp_header.

Comment: I have gone through  the packet decoding stuff before. Anyway you re-iterated my intuition to stick with the same. Thanks pal !